# Play game saves ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution doesn't invoke save function

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, google-cloud-save

Good day!
I am new to Google Play Services and  want to save JSON(string) into the cloud and it doesn't work.  I narrowed down a problem through phone and debug texts and realized that a function from  *((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution* is not called which is strange because in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcxmFWKx0T8) that I watched everything worked and the user logged in successfuly.
here is a code snippet with a comments and a function that is not invoked(I can send a whole script if needed also). Is there something else I am missing?

```
public void OpenSaveToCloud(bool saving)
    {
       // debugtext.text = "hello";
        if(Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
          debugtext.text = "Authorized and proceed to save";
            issaving = saving;
            ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution
                (SAVE_NAME, GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
                ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, SavedGameOpen);   //SavedGame open must be called
         }
         else{
             debugtext.text = "No  authentication";
         }
    }
 
    private void SavedGameOpen(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata meta)//this function is not called
    {
        if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
        {
           // debugtext.text = "hello in save1";
            if (issaving)//if is saving is true we are saving our data to cloud
            {
                debugtext.text = "Saving....";
                byte[] data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetDataToStoreinCloud());
                SavedGameMetadataUpdate update = new SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder().Build();
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.CommitUpdate(meta, update, data, SaveUpdate);
            }
            else//if is saving is false we are opening our saved data from cloud
            {
                debugtext.text = "Loading...";
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ReadBinaryData(meta, ReadDataFromCloud);
            }
        }
        else{
            debugtext.text = "Save request status broke";
        }
    }
```

What I checked twice before posting question:

- Turned on Saved Games in google console
- made build with your keystore and password
- add  email id in game service's tester section

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is that you have to initialize save games from start as well and I didn't know that so answer would be

```
if (platform == null)
        {
            PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().EnableSavedGames().Build();
            PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
            platform = PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        }
```